# How do I store the select column in a variable?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How do I store the select column in a variable?

I tried this, but it throws me an error "Incorrect syntax":

```
declare @EmpId int
SELECT  dbo.Employee.Id as @EmpId FROM  dbo.Employee
```

Comment: If the other answers aren't helping because you want to process more than one row, it would help to know what you want to do with the EmpIds.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

```
select @EmpID = ID from dbo.Employee
```

Or

```
set @EmpID =(select id from dbo.Employee)
```

> Note that the select query might return more than one value or rows. so you can write a select query  that must return one row.

If you would like to add more columns to one variable(MS SQL), there is an option to use table defined variable

```
DECLARE @sampleTable TABLE(column1 type1)
INSERT INTO @sampleTable
SELECT columnsNumberEqualInsampleTable FROM .. WHERE ..
```

As table type variable do not exist in Oracle and others, you would have to define it:

```
DECLARE TYPE type_name IS TABLE OF (column_type | variable%TYPE | table.column%TYPE [NOT NULL] INDEX BY BINARY INTEGER;
```

-- Then to declare a TABLE variable of this type: `variable_name type_name;`

-- Assigning values to a TABLE variable: `variable_name(n).field_name := 'some text'`;

-- Where 'n' is the index value

Comment: Msg 141, Level 15, State 1, Line 19
A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Comment: @Abu - You would need to assign **all** columns in the select list to variables. You can't mix a normal select that returns a result to the client with one that assigns to variables. You could obviously do `SELECT @var1 as somecol, @var2 as anothercol` immediately afterwards though.

Comment: Can you do this with say selecting five columns but only placing one into a temp variable?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming such a query would return a single row, you could use either

```
select @EmpId = Id from dbo.Employee
```

Or

```
set @EmpId = (select Id from dbo.Employee)
```

Comment: what if i i have more than a single rows? how would you handle

Comment: @Abu Hamzah: You can't. A variable can only hold one value. If the query returns more than one row, which value would you expect to be placed in the variable?

Comment: in my situation i have 2 column names that i should be holding 1)EmpId, 2) RegId - it might have more than one row or just one row and i am holding in a variable to compare with others.. not sure if this is the right approach.

Comment: add 'top 1' to query if there is more than one row, or 'where id = ..' condition

Answer (score 2):

This is how to assign a value to a variable:

```
SELECT @EmpID = Id
  FROM dbo.Employee
```

However, the above query is returning more than one value.  You'll need to add a `WHERE` clause in order to return a single `Id` value.