# How to Select from a variable?

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dmv

My helper function for executing a DMV query:

```
Function DMV_Query($DMV_Query) {
## Prepare the connection string based on information provided
$connectionString = "Provider=msolap;Data Source=$AS_Server;Initial Catalog=$CUBE;"

## Connect to the data source and open
$connection = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $connectionString
$command = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand
$command.Connection = $connection 
$command.CommandText = $DMV_Query 
$connection.Open()

## Fetch the results, and close the connection
$adapter = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter #$command
$adapter.SelectCommand = $command 
$dataset = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
[void] $adapter.Fill($dataSet)
$connection.Close()

## Return all of the rows from their query
$dataSet.Tables[0]
}
```

Sample call:

```
$dmvResult = DMV_Query 'SELECT [SESSION_ID], [SESSION_SPID]
                        FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS'
$dmvResult
```

Sample of the content stored in `$dmvResult`:

```
PS> $dmvResult | ConvertTo-Csv
"SESSION_ID","SESSION_SPID"     
"D0kl8975r6df65","5567"
"fghu5r67f65","2234"
```

I want to select all columns from the `$dmvResult` variable and insert them into a SQL table. Is this the way I can select from a variable?

```
# Doesn't work.

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
SELECT * FROM @dmvResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: The answer below may be of interest as an exercise in *advanced string interpolation in PowerShell*, but given that `$dmvResult` contains the rows of an existing `DataTable` object returned form a previous query, using a *bulk-copy operation* is simpler and far more efficient, as discovered by [Cataster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8397835/cataster) themselves: see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54471629/45375).

---

It looks like you're trying to create a T-SQL statement by constructing a string in PowerShell that incorporates the result of a previous query, `$dmvResult`.

Since **T-SQL knows nothing about PowerShell variables, you need to *explicitly incorporate all values* to pass to your `INSERT INTO` statement in the statement *string***.

Here's an example, based on your sample data, **using PowerShell's powerful *expandable strings*** (string interpolation; for background, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49031158/45375)):

```
# Sample query result / imported CSV.
$dmvResult =
  [pscustomobject] @{ SESSION_ID = 'D0kl8975r6df65'; SESSION_SPID = 5567 },
  [pscustomobject] @{ SESSION_ID = 'fghu5r67f65'; SESSION_SPID = 2234 }

# Construct the INSERT INTO statement from $dmvResult, using an expandable
# string ("..." with $variable and $(<command> references))
$insertStatement = @"
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
  ($($dmvResult[0].psobject.properties.name -join ', '))
VALUES
  $(
    @(foreach ($obj in $dmvResult) {
      $values = foreach ($value in $obj.psobject.properties.value) {
        if ($value -is [string]) { "`"$value`"" } else { $value }
      }
      '(' + ($values -join ', ') + ')'
    }) -join ",`n  "
  )
"@

# Output the constructed statement string.
$insertStatement
```

Note that the stringification of the property values may need to be made more sophisticated, depending on your data; the code above distinguishes just between strings and non-strings: the former are stringified with enclosing `"..."`, the latter as-is.

The above yields:

```sql
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
  (SESSION_ID, SESSION_SPID)
VALUES
  ("D0kl8975r6df65", 5567),
  ("fghu5r67f65", 2234)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the query like below,Dont store the value in variable..

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table]
SELECT [SESSION_ID]
      ,[SESSION_SPID]`enter code here`
FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS
```

Comment: the reason im stroing is because 1. thats a DMV query that executes on SSAS cube object which requires an SSAS connection and 2. because i am initially exporting the data to csv file before inserting, so i want to execute this query separately anayways for this other purpose (csv)...i didnt include csv portion because its irrelevant to main question and didnt want to make thread too detailed. however, i think i have found a way...maybe i have to use dynamic query to declare $dmvResult first?

Comment: Use Temp table to store the value and insert into table..you cant use variable to store multiple column

Comment: refer -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120817/how-do-i-store-the-select-column-in-a-variable

Comment: but if thats the case, then how come $dmvResult | Export-Csv is able to export more than one row/column if $dmvResult is holding just one value? i thought it was storing the entire DMV table result because i can see the csv exported file have an entire table structure full of data

Comment: @pratheshp: Your answer misses that there's _PowerShell_ involved in the question: the initial query's results are stored _in a PowerShell variable_, and the OP then wants to use these results _from PowerShell_ in a subsequent SQL operation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, BulkCopy!

```
$dmvResult = DMV_Query 'SELECT [SESSION_ID]
      ,[SESSION_SPID]
FROM $SYSTEM.DISCOVER_SESSIONS';

$ConnectionString ='Data Source=$server; Database=$database; Trusted_Connection=True;'
$bulkCopy = new-object Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy($ConnectionString)
$bulkCopy.DestinationTableName=$Table
$bulkCopy.WriteToServer($dmvResult)
```

This however does not map the columns correctly if they are not in order, as BulkCopy copies by position, not by name match

Comment: Given that this is not a full answer and that you've since solved the implied question here as evidenced by https://stackoverflow.com/q/54471629/45375 (in the context of a follow-up question), which my answer now links to, please delete this post.